# How can I connect to the same database in a parent and child component in next.js

Tags: sql, reactjs, database, postgresql, next.js

I am creating an app on next.js and I have two components I am creating in two different files. I am connecting to a postgresql database in my Server Component "Display". Now within this component I am creating mutliple "TableCell" components that are Client Components. I want my TableCell componenets to also have access to the same database so that I can make queries from both files. How can I connect to my database in my TableCell component. I have tried passing the connection down as props, but that doesn't work. I also tried using CreateContext but I can't use it in a server component. [Preview of my connection being made in Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2P66.png)[Preview of how I render TableCell within Display[Preview of my TableCell component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDBVN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRtk9.png)

I have tried passing the connection down as props, but that doesn't work. I also tried using CreateContext but I can't use it in a server component.

Comment: You should add the code or create a smaller example that can reproduce your issue, it's not easy to understand what you're doing with some badly cut images. Regardless, you should fetch the data once in the parent component and pass the data down as props to its childs TableCell in order to display it.

Comment: Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the section **Help others reproduce the problem**. Instead of posting links to images, post the code as editable text in the question itself.